# Mapping a field to geo-point after indexing data in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have already created index and imported data into index, but without mapping. My data has a filed "geolocatoin":"lat,lng". Now i want to run geo-spatial queries based on geolocation. So i mapped the filed geolocation to geo-point using the following curl command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index/place/_mapping?ignore_conflicts=true' -d '
{    
    "place" : {
        "properties" : {        
        "geolocation" : { "type" : "geo_point" }        
        }
    }
}'
```

i got `{"acknowledged":true}` as response.

but when i tried to run geo-spatial query, it throws the error

```
field [geolocation] is not a geo_point field];
```

So. whether i have reindex after mapping. But reindexing is not possible because its a large dataset. How can i accomplish this. Please share your ideas....

Comment: This is not possible at the moment, dump your data and create the mapping first. then re-index your data. Alternatively, have a [look at this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/).

Comment: @Thorsten thanks a lot..in documentation i read that... re-indexing some 2L data is impossible. Thats y i am looking for some other options..

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must reindex after mapping for some mapping type. You can try write a script to update all documents to move your old field to new field with good mapping.

If your index is used for the production, you can try create an alias to your current index and you use it in your program. You create a new index with good mapping and after reindex, you switch your alias on your index.